# How to access to module variables from main application FLEX

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Error: Access of possibly undefined property maxCount throught a reference with static mx.core.IVisualElement

```
<s:ModuleLoader id="ball" url="Ball.swf" ready="initBall();"/>

        public function initBall():void {

            ball.child.maxCount = maxScore;

        }
```

I am trying to access the property after the ready event is fired, but why the compiler says that these variable is undefined?, i've defined it in the module, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's defined at runtime. But at compile time `child` variable is of type IVisualElement. Call dynamic property `ball.child["maxCount"] = maxScor`;
Or use interface better.